# Using my DB Server instead of Tableau server

Tags: ipad, tableau-api

I am newbie to Tableau software. Let me explain my understanding on this. I installed "tableau mobile" app in my ipad. When opening the app, it prompts for domain name and authentication details. For that i need to install the "Tableau Server" in PC and get the username and password. Now my question is **instead of using "Tableau Server", can i use my own DB Server?** I don't want to use the tableau server between my ipad client and  DB server.  Is this possible? Is that tableau software provides this flexibility? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tableau Mobile app is in essence a reskinned browser that is designed to work with Tableau Server. Tableau Server is a web server that is used to share data sources and dashboards created and published using Tableau Desktop.

In short, it is not possible to connect the Tableau Mobile app to a DB server that is not an instance of Tableau Server.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have one more question. I need a standalone app like "Tableau Desktop" for iPad. Is that app available for iPad ?

Comment: At present, Tableau Desktop is only available on Windows. A native Mac version of Tableau Desktop is being developed as we speak, but I am not sure if a native iOS version is also in development.